# How to show thousand in k format for bar values in chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have many bars with a thousand values like 35000, 12000, and 76560. So these values are getting overlapped with each other. I need to change `Bar values` not `StepSize`.

I want to show these values 35k, 12k and 76.5k format. This is my code

```
public barStatus() {
  var colors = ['#299DFF', '#80FFFF', '#F8362B', ];
  var chBar = document.getElementById("chBar");
  var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Success',
      data: [35000, 12000, 76560],
      backgroundColor: colors[0]
    }, ]
  }
  var barOptions_stacked = {
    onClick: this.Status,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'left',
        formatter: Math.round,
        font: {
          color: 'black'
        }
      },
    },
    hover: {
      animationDuration: 0
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 0.5,
          categoryPercentage: 0.5
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        type: 'logarithmic',
        position: 'left',
        ticks: {
          min: 0, //minimum tick
          max: 100000, //maximum tick
          callback: function (value, index, values) {
            return Number(value.toString()); //pass tick values as a string into Number function
          }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function (chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
          chartObj.ticks = [];
          chartObj.ticks.push(0);
          chartObj.ticks.push(10);
          chartObj.ticks.push(100);
          chartObj.ticks.push(1000);
          chartObj.ticks.push(10000);
          chartObj.ticks.push(100000);
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: false
      }]
    },
  };
  this.Canvas = document.getElementById("chBar");
  this.chart = new Chart(this.Canvas, {
    type: "bar",
    data: chartData,
    options: barOptions_stacked
  });
}
```

How can I do that?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check the length of the number as a string. Then cut of at the right length and add a `'k'` after it.

Comment: `k` can stand for *times a thousand*, so dividing by thousand and adding the string `'k'` after it is also a way to do it. Both do need some additional checks, though.

Comment: you only want the format to be shown on tooltips that show the value of the point on the graph, or to adopt that format also in labeling of the yAxes?

Comment: @PeterDarmis - Not need for tooltip. Needed for yAx values/labels

Comment: At the time i asked i had already started to include the tooltip change so i added both ways in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function in formatter option inside datalabels plugin configuration:

```
 datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "left",
        formatter: function(context) {
          return context / 1000 + "k";
        },
        font: {
          color: "black"
        }
      }
```

You can check the solution in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-thousand?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you want to change the format of a number on the top of bar you need to change the configuration of datalabels plugin for achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

For styling only the labels you want something like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12000, 1900, 3000, 5000, 2201, 3492]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  myChart.options.scales = {
    xAxes: [],
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      type: 'logarithmic',
      position: 'left',
      ticks: {
        min: 0, //minimum tick
        max: 100000, //maximum tick
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return Number((value / 1000).toString()) + 'K'; //pass tick values as a string into Number function
        }
      },
      afterBuildTicks: function(chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
        chartObj.ticks = [];
        chartObj.ticks.push(0);
        chartObj.ticks.push(10);
        chartObj.ticks.push(100);
        chartObj.ticks.push(1000);
        chartObj.ticks.push(10000);
        chartObj.ticks.push(100000);
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  };
  myChart.update();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

In case you want to change the format of the value shown when hovering the chart and displaying the value inside the tooltip, you need to use the tooltip callbacks.

For example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12000, 1900, 3000, 5000, 2201, 3492]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return (tooltipItem.yLabel/1000)+'K';
                }
            }
        },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  myChart.options.scales = {
    xAxes: [],
    yAxes: [ {
      gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        type: 'logarithmic',
        position: 'left',
        ticks: {
          min: 0, //minimum tick
          max: 100000, //maximum tick
          callback: function (value, index, values) {
            return Number((value/1000).toString())+'K'; //pass tick values as a string into Number function
          }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function (chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
          chartObj.ticks = [];
          chartObj.ticks.push(0);
          chartObj.ticks.push(10);
          chartObj.ticks.push(100);
          chartObj.ticks.push(1000);
          chartObj.ticks.push(10000);
          chartObj.ticks.push(100000);
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        }
    }
    ]
  };
  myChart.update();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Last example involves the plugin you use in your question.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      datalabels: {
        color: '#000'
      },
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12000, 1900, 3000, 5000, 2201, 3492]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: '#000',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex] + ': ' + Math.round(value / 1000) + 'K';
        }
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return (tooltipItem.yLabel / 1000) + 'K';
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  myChart.options.scales = {
    xAxes: [],
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      type: 'logarithmic',
      position: 'left',
      ticks: {
        min: 0, //minimum tick
        max: 100000, //maximum tick
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return Number((value / 1000).toString()) + 'K'; //pass tick values as a string into Number function
        }
      },
      afterBuildTicks: function(chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
        chartObj.ticks = [];
        chartObj.ticks.push(0);
        chartObj.ticks.push(10);
        chartObj.ticks.push(100);
        chartObj.ticks.push(1000);
        chartObj.ticks.push(10000);
        chartObj.ticks.push(100000);
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  };
  myChart.update();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: In your first code snippet you changed `stepsize in k format` which I am not looking for. In 2nd  code snippet you did for tooltip which again I am not looking for. Please check screenshot in my question. I need circle values in k format.

Comment: @R15 i was away for a while did not see the screenshot...

Comment: No issue! still you can correct your answer. I will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution (just now). In `config` `option` its will have `animation` and call back with function `onComplete`. Here you can draw the label with any format you want. [Please see this picture for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XekxJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not share code as image. Please use SO built-in code formatting tools.